# Converting json data to html

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

I'm trying to convert json data from a website and display it in html:

```
var obj = 'http://ip-api.com/json';
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = obj.country + ", " + obj.as;
```

I am trying to get the JSON code from a url called http://ip-api.com/json, and I am trying to get the data to be read and then shown into html, can anyone help?

Comment: This is probably the most basic thing that any JS program ever does. There are about 101 ways to approach it, all of them covered in hundreds and thousands of intros, tutorials, and blog posts.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to perform an Ajax call to fetch the remote the json. I suggest you to use jQuery library for this.

Before </body>:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(obj) { 
    jQuery("#info").html(obj.country + ", " + obj.as); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The information on the website didnt display on the html doc?

Comment: Are you running this html in your local machine? If so, replace `src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"` by `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"`

Comment: I am running it off a local machine and what am I doing wrong because the JSON data wont display on the html
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(obj) { 
    jQuery("#info").html(obj.country + ", " + obj.as); 
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: And where is `#info` HTML container??

Comment: I'm clearly not to experienced with html, but I get the concept and I am working on it, but I don't really understand what you mean by HTML container

Comment: `<div id="#info"></div>` that's the container html element for the output info (the element that will be filled up with the info retrieved by the Ajax call). Place the container just below <body>;

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/r4aj5y8l54dksv7/index.html look at what I have down for code, I only have that file and it's ran off nothing else. I still can't get it to display on the html code.

Comment: @Roto check my snippet, it's working now and should give you the basic idea how to do it.

Comment: You're not following my instructions. `<div id="#info"></div>` should go *just below* opening <body> tag, that means it's gonna be placed *just above* the opening <script> tag, according to the html file you hosted in mediafire.

Comment: *I suggest you to use jQuery library for this* Why?

Comment: @torazaburo , you know what jQuery is, right? And the amount of code,  work and time it would save for him while working with Ajax requests? Now, you give me a good reason why not to use jQuery in his code (the use of another JS library would be acceptable, the use of native JS would not).